# How to scroll down a web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hy community,
I have used the following code for scrolling pages

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

It worked fine for almost all of the web pages but I recently encountered a web page where this snippet doesn't work. Go to this link https://www.holonis.com/christineboctor, Click on Followers and then try to scroll down with this code and it won't work. Is there anyone who knows how to deal with it? I am novice in JavaScript, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: error on website nothing to display

Comment: can you try it with proxy? the website is called holonis

Comment: may be there is error in  vender

Comment: it scrolls down when we do it manually but not with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
       var scrolltop = $('.w-modal-follow-list.w-modal-followers').offset().top ;
       window.scrollTo(0, scrolltop );
```

`.offset().top` will find position of `div` from top and you can set it like `window.scrollTo(0, scrolltop )`

Answer (score -2):

Try 
    `$('.w-modal-follow-list.w-modal-followers').scrollTop(500)`.
Where 500 is your scroll value.

Comment: Is there any way we can use pure javascript to achieve this?

Comment: i am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null  at <anonymous>:1:44"

Comment: Can you show me the exact code you're trying to use. Because it works fine when i type
"$('.w-modal-follow-list.w-modal-followers').scrollTop(500)"
on my console i chrome.

Comment: Not a hardcoded value needed if the target is at a position of 2000 then it will not scroll to that targeted div